# WebSphere Liberty Profile DataSource and CDI

Tags: datasource, cdi, code-injection, entitymanager, websphere-liberty

I have setup my Development environment with a WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6.

I configured a DataSource in my **server.xml**

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/DB" transactional="true" type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
  <jdbcDriver libraryRef="dblib" />
  <connectionManager maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="2" />
  <properties.oracle URL="MYURL" user="usr" password="pw" />
</dataSource>
```

In my project I inject my EntityManagers using CDI. Everything works pretty fine. But my problem is that I can't inject a new EntityManager after I've done it once.

I have a **EntityManagerProducer** class, which generates my EntityManagers.

```
class EntityManagerProducer {
    @PersistenceUnit(name = "DB")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager create() {
        EntityManager tmp = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        LoggerFactory.info(Constants.AppName, "EntityManager " + tmp.toString() + " freigegeben.");
        return this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void dispose(@Disposes @Default EntityManager entityManager) {
        if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityManager.close();
            LoggerFactory.info(Constants.AppName, "EntityManager " + entityManager.toString() + " beseitigt.");
        }
    }
}
```

The dispose() method never gets called, so I think the EntityManager never gets closed and that's why I won't get a new one??

Help would be great...

Comment: Is your EntityManagerProducer class declared as a bean?  The @Disposes spec states that the dispose method must be declared on a managed or session bean class.

Comment: I added the @ManagedBean annotation, but that didn't solve the problem - again the first call works, at the second call I get a NullPointerException...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aguibert was right!

Adding `@RequestScoped` to the Class and to the create() method did it!

Thank you!